# List all tables in Postgres that contain a boolean type column with NULL values?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Is there a way to list all tables within information schema which contain a boolean type column with NULL values? If I have a names of the tables, I can later on use query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name IS NULL
```

Of course, if there is a way to list all rows from all the tables with single query, that would be even faster.

Doing this step by step would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column_name IS NULL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE column_name IS NULL
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE column_name IS NULL
...
```

Tables are already populated, for new database, such columns should have `NOT NULL` constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running postgresql 9.0+, you can use an anonymous plpgsql block to execute some dynamic SQL.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    rec         RECORD;
    v_result    INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN 
        SELECT 'select 1 from ' || quote_ident(n.nspname) ||'.'|| quote_ident(c.relname) ||
                    ' where ' || quote_ident(a.attname) || ' IS NULL LIMIT 1' as qry_to_run,
                n.nspname||'.'||c.relname as tbl,
                a.attname as col
        FROM pg_class as c
        INNER JOIN pg_attribute as a ON (a.attrelid = c.oid)
        INNER JOIN pg_type as t ON (t.oid = a.atttypid)
        LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
        WHERE a.attnum >= 1
        AND c.relkind = 'r'
        AND pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) = 'boolean'
        AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog','information_schema')
        AND a.attnotnull IS NOT TRUE
    LOOP
        EXECUTE rec.qry_to_run INTO v_result;
        IF v_result = 1 THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'Table % has NULLs in the BOOLEAN field %', rec.tbl,rec.col;
            v_result := 0;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: +1 Nice work! I have a couple of suggestions, more than fit into a comment, so I added another answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, column_name, ordinal_position  
FROM information_schema.columns  
WHERE table_schema <> 'pg_catalog' AND data_type = 'boolean';
```

and:

```
DO $$  
DECLARE 
r record;
s record;  
BEGIN  
FOR r IN    SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, column_name, ordinal_position 
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE table_schema <> 'pg_catalog' AND data_type = 'boolean'  
LOOP  
    FOR s IN EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || quote_literal(r.table_schema) || ', ' || quote_literal(r.table_name) || ', ' || quote_literal(r.column_name) || ' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' || quote_ident(r.table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(r.table_name) || ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(r.column_name) || ' IS NULL);'  
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '** % % %', quote_ident(r.table_schema), quote_ident(r.table_name), quote_ident(r.column_name);
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;  
END  
$$;
```

Osvaldo

Comment: Osvaldo, thank you for you reply. I corrected the query inside the loop:
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident(r.table_name) || ' WHERE ' || quote_ident(r.column_name) || ' IS NULL;'; ,now it executes, but no results.

Answer (score 2):

This advances [@bma's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17680024/939860) to make it shorter, faster and a bit smarter:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   rec    record;
  _found  boolean;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN 
      SELECT format('SELECT TRUE FROM %s WHERE %I IS NULL LIMIT 1'
                   , c.oid::regclass, a.attname) AS qry_to_run
            ,c.oid::regclass AS tbl
            ,a.attname       AS col
      FROM   pg_namespace n 
      JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid 
      JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
      WHERE  n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND    n.nspname NOT LIKE 'pg_%'  -- exclude system, temp, toast tbls
      AND    c.relkind = 'r'
      AND    a.attnum > 0
      AND    a.atttypid = 'boolean'::regtype
      AND    a.attnotnull = FALSE
      AND    a.attisdropped = FALSE

   LOOP
      EXECUTE rec.qry_to_run INTO _found;

      IF _found THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Table % has NULLs in the BOOLEAN field %'
                    , rec.tbl,rec.col;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END
$$;
```